# Creating bootable USB drive on Linux with windows 10 .iso

Tags: linux, boot, usb, formatting, iso-image

I already know this question is going to be downvoted into oblivion but, I would like to know some simple ways I can create a bootable USB drive with a Windows 10 .iso file on Linux. The distribution I am running is Manjaro with KDE Plasma 5.22.3. I recently installed Manjaro with switching to it as my main OS in mind but I realized that I don't want to have the risk of messing up my system once I accidentally assigned my entire drive to me as the owner instead of root removing root from having access to /etc/sudo.conf and had to reinstall the entire system.

I have tried installing balena etcher from the AUR but it just won't quite work and I haven't seen any other people on here asking this question for Manjaro distributions. I would like to know any other simple ways that I can create a bootable USB drive so I can run the windows installer and remove Manjaro completely. Additionally, I would also like to know if I have to format my USB drive to have an exFAT or a fat32 filesystem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This shouldn't be downvoted as it is a pretty reasonable question, but we do have many questions on this topic already. If anything you should be looking at the duplicates and then telling us if you have a problem actually applying them.

Comment: The reason you were [downvoted at Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68564975/creating-bootable-usb-drive-on-linux-with-windows-10-iso) is because that site is specifically for programming and development questions, while this site is more for general home computing problems and excludes programming questions.